# Raspberry Pi - stopping while loop with push switch

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, raspberry-pi3, gpio, led

Just to save time, the code starts a loop for two leds blinking back and forth after pushing a switch on the right. What I've been trying to do --without success obviously-- is stop the while loop by pressing a second switch on the left to turn both leds off and the code completely stop. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated it.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

leftLED = 22
rightLED = 18
leftSWITCH = 24
rightSWITCH = 16

GPIO.setup(leftLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(rightLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(leftSWITCH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(rightSWITCH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.output(leftLED, False)
GPIO.output(rightLED, False)
try:
    print("press the left button to start. Press the right button to stop.")
while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(leftSWITCH)
    if input_state == False:

        while True:
            input_state1 = GPIO.input(rightSWITCH)

            GPIO.output(rightLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(.5)

            GPIO.output(rightLED, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(.1)

            GPIO.output(leftLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(.5)

            GPIO.output(leftLED, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(.1)

          if input_state1 == False:
            break





 finally:
     GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Your inside `while` loop is an infinite loop: the condition is `while True` and there are no break statements in the loop. How have you tried checking the state of the left switch?

Comment: I edited my code, it doesn't work, but I don't know why, and I apologize I'm not used to the site yet.

Comment: Is it intentional that you're configuring one switch with `PUD_DOWN` and the other with `PUD_UP`?

Comment: That was me experimenting. They should both be up I take it? I fixed it in my code. But changing both switches to UP Still doesn't cancel the infinite loop.

Comment: @larsks I read what `PUD_UP` and `PUD_DOWN` actually do and I can say both switches are wired for 3.3v so i set both switches to `PUD_UP`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with the raspberry pi and GPIO pins, bu I've got an idea.
I know that this is not a working code.

My idea is to run a while loop and checking if a button is pressed.

If the left switch is pressed and the tread is not started it will start a thread, wich will let the leds blink.

If the right switch is pressed and the leds are already blinking, the thread will be terminated.

```
import threading

def led_blink():
  # led off
  # sleep
  # led on
  # sleep

leds_are_blinking = False
while True:
  if left_switch == True and not leds_are_blinking:
    thread = threading.tread(target="led_blink")
    thread.start()
    leds_are_blinking = True
  if right_switch == True and leds_are_blinking:
    thread.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code substantially works as written.  I've simplified it down to the following, which operates correctly on my Pi (note that I've changed the pin numbers because I already had wires on these):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

leftSWITCH = 16
rightSWITCH = 18

GPIO.setup(leftSWITCH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(rightSWITCH, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:
    print('press the left button to start. Press the right button to stop.')

    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(leftSWITCH)
        if input_state == False:
            print('left button was pressed!')
            while True:
                input_state1 = GPIO.input(rightSWITCH)

                print('.', end='', flush=True)
                time.sleep(1)

                if input_state1 == False:
                    print('right button was pressed!')
                    break

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

There are some indendation issues with the code in your question that may be causing problems; it's hard to tell if they are simply formatting issues in the question or if they represent actual problems in your code.

While the above code works, they is substantial room for improvement: in particular, the outer loop is a "busy wait"; your code is constantly looping and checking the left switch.  A better solution would be to use a blocking wait, for example using the `wait_for_edge` method:

```
try:
    print('press the left button to start. Press the right button to stop.')

    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(leftSWITCH, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=100)
        print('left button was pressed!')
        while True:
            input_state1 = GPIO.input(rightSWITCH)

            print('.', end='', flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)

            if input_state1 == False:
                print('right button was pressed!')
                break

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```